# When loop over children how can I include also the parent and not only the children?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private static Renderer TraverseHierarchy(Transform root, int childIndex)
    {
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer();

        foreach(Transform child in root)
        {
            // Deal with child
            if (child.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>() != null)
            {
                renderer = Selection.gameObjects[childIndex].GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>(true);
            }

            if (child.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null)
            {
                renderer = Selection.gameObjects[childIndex].GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>(true);
            }
        }

        return renderer;
    }
```

The problem is when an object don't have any children. For example I have a 3d cube without any children.
It will never pass this line and will never get inside the loop :

```
foreach(Transform child in root)
```

That's why I want to include the root as parent and also the children of this root if there are any children.  Not recursive ! only the parent and his children if there are any children.

There might be two cases :

- The root don't have any children then just check the root for one of the mesh renderers.
- The root have children in this case check for one of the renderers on the root and his children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check for childCount of root? Something like this:

```
   private static Renderer TraverseHierarchy(Transform root, int childIndex)
   {
        if (root.childCount == 0)
        {
            var skinnedMesh = root.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
            if (skinnedMesh) return skinnedMesh;
            
            var mesh = root.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            if (mesh) return mesh;
        }
        
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
      // your child logic
   }
```